# Regexp matching except

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match some paths, but not others via regexp.  I want to match anything that starts with "/profile/" that is NOT one of the following:

- /profile/attributes
- /profile/essays
- /profile/edit

Here is the regex I'm trying to use that doesn't seem to be working:

```
^/profile/(?!attributes|essays|edit)$
```

For example, none of these URLs are properly matching the above:

- /profile/matt
- /profile/127
- /profile/-591m!40v81,ma/asdf?foo=bar#page1

Comment: believe you are forgetting your .* to chew up the rest of the line before hitting eol

Comment: What about `/profile/attributes?x=1`, `/profile/attributes/foo`, `/profile/attributes#bar`, `/profile/attributes2`, `/profile/./attributes`, `/profile//attributes`, `/profile/..`? Should they match or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to say that there can be any characters until the end of the string:

```
^/profile/(?!attributes|essays|edit).*$
```

Removing the end-of-string anchor would also work:

```
^/profile/(?!attributes|essays|edit)
```

And you may want to be more restrictive in your negative lookahead to avoid excluding `/profile/editor`:

```
^/profile/(?!(?:attributes|essays|edit)$)
```

Comment: ^/profile/(?!(?:attributes|essays|edit)$)
should be changed to: ^/profile/(?!(?:attributes|essays|edit)).*$ ... otherwise you will match for paths that have additional stuff after it, such as /profile/essays/hello_world.txt

Comment: to take into account something like editor as you mentioned, maybe have it also verify ($|/) ::: ^/profile/(?!(?:attributes|essays|edit)($|/))

Comment: in that case it could suck up anything until it hits ($|/) right? :::>>> m = re.compile("^/profile/(?!(?:attributes|essays|edit).*?($|/))")
>>> m.search('/profile/essays/hello_world.txt')
>>> m.search('/profile/essaysd/hello_world.txt')
>>> m.search('/profile/esssysd/hello_world.txt')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10d5828>

Answer (score 1):

comments are hard to read code in, so here is my answer in nice format

```
def mpath(path, ignore_str = 'attributes|essays|edit',anything = True):
    any = ''
    if anything:
        any = '.*?'
    m = re.compile("^/profile/(?!(?:%s)%s($|/)).*$" % (ignore_str,any) )
    match = m.search(path)
    if match:
        return match.group(0)
    else:
        return ''
```

Comment: The code was a little confusing.  Basically what you're getting at is `^/profile/(?!(?:attributes|essays|edit)($|/)).*$`, which is a bit easier for me to read personally. Upvote for the regex.